# Is there any method in EA repositories that I can use in my EA add-in to create custom code generation template in C#?

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I'm working on a C code generator add-in for EA.
I spent quite a lot of time looking for any potential methods from EA repositories that would let me access the EA auto code generation templates. (I'm trying to find a way to create a custom template in C#) But so far I haven't found anything relevant.
I'm wondering if there are methods that I can use to extend Enterprise Architect Add-in Framework, to create a custom code generation template? Or do I need to create a method from scratch?

Comment: Are you looking for T4 templates?

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure what T4 templates are, but I believe the answer is no! :D I meant the auto code generation templates for enterprise architect. :)

Comment: Think about generating code directly using the model without using that crude code generation macro language from Sparx. I've done that once and it was by way easier than the macro stuff. Plus coding in your _own_ language is what you really want. Honestly though, after a while I recognized that code generation is a Fata Morgana.

Comment: Hi qwerty. Thank you. Can you guide me a little about how I can generate code directly from the model? I am trying to do that, but I am kinda lost!

Comment: Well, I could. But a) I found that code generation is a Fata Morgana and b) it can't be explained in the comment. The API gives you access to the classes and how they are related. You traverse that (or take package contents as you like) and for each class you get attributes and operations which you can simply spit out in according files. For a basic generation I would need less than a day. Extras can bloat the whole thing. But I'm cured and waste my time elsewhere ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code generation templates can be included in an MDG.

And you supply the MDG from an add-in, and get your code generation template in EA that way.

In order tell give EA the MDG xml, you have to implement the method `EA_OnInitializeTechnologies`

This is an example taken from my addin [EA JSON](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Toolpack/blob/master/EAJSON/EAJSONAddin.cs)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// return the MDG content for the JSON MDG (so it doesn't have to be loaded separately
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Repository"></param>
    /// <returns>the MDG file contents</returns>
    public override object EA_OnInitializeTechnologies(Repository Repository)
    {
        return Properties.Resources.JSON_MDG;
    }
```

More details on how to generate the MDG file can be found in the [manual](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/16.0/modeling_frameworks/creatingmdgtechnologies.html)

You'll need to check the Code Modules checkbox when generating an MDG technology

[image]

This will allow you to select the code generation templates, datatypes, etc..
[image]

If you don't need the add-in for anything else, you might be able to simply use the MDG instead of the add-in.

Comment: Hi Geert. Thank you. I read the details in the manual, and I had a look at the folder EAJSON in your Enterprise Architect Toolpack to get a better understanding. I have some questions about the EAJSON add-in. 1. Are all of the xml files inside the folder "Files" are generated by EA MDG technology? 2. I still cannot find out how to manipulate code generation templates in C#. Do you know if there is an example or specific guide I can use?

Comment: @Shara, why do you need to manipulate code generation templates in C#? They are supposed to be at-design time artifacts, and should normally not be changed at runtime. Yes, all xml files under Files have been created using EA as described in the manual.

Comment: Ok, I think I have got this all wrong from the beginning! 
Sorry if my questions don't make sense. I was not even familiar with EA when I started working on this project and I'm trying my best to understand it.
All I need to do is create a custom C code generator for EA that generates .c and .h codes from EA state machine diagrams correctly. As you know the dynamic parts of the C code are not generated by current templates in EA. So I chose to create an add-in, instead of modifying the confusing STM_C templates in EA.

Comment: I expected that there should be a way to access the auto code generation templates through an add-in and create one in C#. But now I'm blocked because I cannot figure out how to proceed!

Comment: You either use the templates and let EA generate the code for you, or you generate the code yourself in your add-in. No need to use the templates at all in that case.

Comment: Yes exactly. I am trying to create code generation in my add-in. But the only code generation relevant interface and utility function I could find is "EA.IDualProject.GeneratePackage". And that gene rated the code using the templates in EA. @GeertBellekens

Comment: So if I understood correctly, you are suggesting using MDG technology to implement the code generation in my add-in?

Comment: If you let EA generate the code, there's no added value in writing an add-in. A simple MDG can suffice.